# Python- Finding character(s) in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider I have a string -

```
t= Hello, How are you? My name :Raunak
```

From this string I want to first find the word-

```
name
```

And then, I want to put the value of a variable X as the word after the : sign. For example, here-

```
X=Raunak
```

In every case I know that the thing I want to be value of X is after the : sign.

Comment: Have you consider using regex?

Comment: Show the code you tried. Where are you struck with this?
Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string into list and loop through that list and use `startwith()` to find `:` sign then replace your variable to the word after `:` sign.

```py
t = "Hello, How are you? My name :Raunak"
x = "John"
new_name = ''

after_split = t.split()

for name in after_split:
    if name.startswith(":"):
        new_name = t.replace(name, ":{}".format(x))
        break

print(new_name)
```

result after print

```
Hello, How are you? My name :John
```